# MKMapView pin animation and annotation

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, google-places-api, mkannotation

I'm using the google places API to find some restaurants nearby (based on current location using core location manager); currently, I'm able to drop pins. I use the searchBarSearchButtonClicked method, and inside of a dispatch_async block, I call my method to parse through my serialized data and attribute values to properties of my pin class (class MKAnnotation). I'd like to animate my pin drops, and also actually display annotations...for some reason I had them working before but now they won't show up when I click on the pins.

VIEW CONTROLLER.H

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate,NSURLSessionDelegate> {

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) MKMapView *mapView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchBar *searchBar;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *logo;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIToolbar *toolBar;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *places;

@end
```

VIEW CONTROLLER.M

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.searchBar.text);
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSString *s = [NSString
    stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?keyword=%@&location=%f,%f&radius=5&types=food&key=AIzaSyCg6Ahz_hQ1f2rjKEAWcJKQetblPVjHS-E", self.searchBar.text, locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:s];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSData *dataResponse = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:location];

        NSDictionary *dictionaryReponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataResponse options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *finalResults = [dictionaryReponse objectForKey:@"results"];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self placeAnnotations:finalResults];

    });

    }];
    [task resume];

}

-(void)placeAnnotations:(NSMutableArray *)data {


        for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
            //        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]]) {
            [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
            //        }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < [data count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *place = [data objectAtIndex:i];
            NSDictionary *geo = [place objectForKey:@"geometry"];
            NSDictionary *location = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];
            NSString *name = [place objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSString *vicinity = [place objectForKey:@"vicinity"];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;
            placeCoord.latitude = [[location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
            placeCoord.longitude = [[location objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];


            MapPoint *newPin = [MapPoint new];
            newPin.name = name;
            newPin.address = vicinity;
            newPin.coordinate = placeCoord;

            MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:newPin reuseIdentifier:@"annotation"];
            newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;

            [self.mapView addAnnotation:newPin];

        }


        [self.mapView reloadInputViews];

}
```

I